# .Net Core 3.1 Permissions Issue Based on Project Type

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, .net-core-3.1, sqlclient

I have a problem that I can't seem to figure out on my own.

Basically, I have two solutions on my work computer.

Both are using .Net Core 3.1 Framework, one is the default MVC new project setup (ASP.NET Core Web App (Model View Controller)) running with IIS Express, and one is a simple console application. Both are using the nuget package Microsoft.Data.SqlClient and that is it.

However, the console application errors out on the following code, when trying to Open() the connection:

InnerException = {"Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.dll' or one of its dependencies: Access is denied. (0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))"}

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection("Verified Connection String Here"))
            {
                connection.Open();
                new SqlCommand("SELECT 1", connection).ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
```

The same code when running the MVC web app (Using IIS) works fine!! What could possibly be the issue? What can I troubleshoot next? I suspect it is something with the security settings that I have no control over (I'm at a government organization)

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

McAfee was blocking access to the DLL in the case with running the console project. There was some rule that prevented execution depending on where the project folder was located. I moved it from my users folder and the C:/ drive directly and then it worked.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).